# Ignore changes on terraform aws_dynamodb_table_item for aws replica attributes

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-dynamodb, terraform-provider-aws

I have below terraform code to create the dynamodb table items

```
resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "docroot" {
  count = length(XXX)
  table_name = XXXX
  hash_key   = XXXXX

  item = <<EOF
{
  "XXXX":    { "S": "XXXX, count.index)}" },
  "XXXX": { "S": "XXXX, count.index)}" },
  "XXXX":  { "S": "XXXX, count.index)}" }
}
EOF

}
```

it works fine. but whenever the terraform is executed, the below changes as always there.

```
  #  will be updated in-place
  ~ resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "docroot" {
        
      ~ item       = jsonencode(
          ~ {
              - aws:rep:deleting     = {
                  - BOOL = false
                } -> null
              - aws:rep:updateregion = {
                  - S = "us-west-2"
                } -> null
              - aws:rep:updatetime   = {
                  - N = "1682511411.190001"
                } -> null
                # (3 unchanged elements hidden)
            }
        )
        # (2 unchanged attributes hidden)
    }
```

Tried to add a ignore changes on these attributes

```
 lifecycle {
    ignore_changes=[
      "item.aws:rep:deleting",
    ]
  }
```

This is not working..

```
│ Error: Invalid character
│
│   on xxx.tf line 21, in resource "aws_dynamodb_table_item" "docroot":
│   21:       "item.aws:rep:deleting",
│
│ Expected an attribute access or an index operator.`

Terraform version and Provider:
Terraform v1.1.6
+ provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws v4.64.0
```

Comment: I would suggest moving to a newer version of Terraform.

Comment: Tried with Terraform v1.4.6... still the same

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add you may not need the `lifecycle` block then at all. :)

Comment: tried without lifecycle...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aws replica attributes changes in aws_dynamodb_table_items was due to bug in aws provider.
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/30690 it was introduced in 4.19. so if the aws version is locked at 4.18.0 till the bug is fixed, the changes won't show up.